# Updating the odds / probability once user plays a bet

Tags: probability, prediction

I am working on an assignment in which I have created a game in which user will bet on outcome of a game. Team A will win or not.

if win =     Invest 7 get 10
if not win = Invest 5 get 10

I have an initial 20 as seed money. Now people have started to place bet. Let's say 
First player place a bet of 7.

I want to now update the odds/probability, but I am confuse on how do I update it ? can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Can you please share what you have attempted this far and what is not working for you?

Comment: I am kind of stuck here. I don't know how to update the probability once people start betting.